# Calling a C# overloaded method with out parameters from F#

Tags: f#

I have the following F# code to handle a Gtk.TreeView event:

```
  tree.CursorChanged.Add(fun (e : EventArgs) -> 
      let selection = tree.Selection
      let mutable iter = new TreeIter ()
      if selection.GetSelected(&iter) then
        Console.WriteLine("Path of selected row = {0}", model.GetPath(iter))
      )
```

`selection.GetSelected` has two overloads, with signatures

```cs
bool GetSelected(out TreeIter, out ITreeModel)
```

and

```cs
bool GetSelected(out TreeIter)
```

which is preventing me from using the tuple-returning version as described in [this post](http://luketopia.net/2014/02/05/fsharp-and-output-parameters/):

```
let selection = tree.Selection
match selection.GetSelected() with
| true, iter -> // success
| _ -> // failure
```

Is there any way to specify which `GetSelected` overload I want with the latter syntax?

**Edit:**
To clarify the question, I know what method signature I want; I just don't know how to specify it. For instance, I tried this, which didn't work:

```
let f : (byref<TreeIter> -> bool) = selection.GetSelected
match f() with
| true, iter -> // success
| _ -> // failure
```

Comment: How about `| true, iter, _ -> // success`?

Comment: nope, fails with the method resolution error:

 A unique overload for method 'GetSelected' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: TreeSelection.GetSelected(iter: byref<TreeIter>) : bool, TreeSelection.GetSelected(model: byref<ITreeModel>, iter: byref<TreeIter>) : bool

Comment: Did the error message not give you the type signature you need to apply to the function you desire?  `TreeSelection.GetSelected(iter: byref<TreeIter>) : bool`

Comment: yes, but i don't know how to specify that while also getting the F# magic of passing in no arguments and getting the out params back as part of the return value. that's what i was asking in the first place :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think

```
match selection.GetSelected() : bool*_ with
...
```

should work.

Comment: perfect, thanks! should have figured out i needed to specify the f# signature, not the c# one.